# Command line that gives the path to `texmf-dist` - TeX Live (MiKTeX ?)

Tags: texlive, command-line

Is there a command line that gives the path to the folder texmf-dist where all the standard sty files are installed ?

If the answer is positive, is there the same thing for MiKTeX ?

Comment: `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFDIST` gives `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9` on my MikTeX and indeed that is the root of the TDS tree in the sense that for example `article.cls` is at `<TEXMFDIST>/tex/latex/base/article.cls` i.e. `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls`. (I didn't check on TeX live, but I'm pretty sure `TEXMFDIST` will work there as well, `TEXMFHOME` and `TEXMFLOCAL` definitely work)

Comment: Thanks that does the job. I have built a tiny Python script to minimize imports. For exemple I used to import both `tkz-tab` and `tikz` but `tkz-tab` already imports `tikz`. This is why I would like to generalize this tiny script for other distribtions.

Comment: it doesn't really hurt to reference a package twice, latex only includes it once

Comment: You're right but this allows to have the shortest list of imports.